# Using Sourceforge Safe C Library in Visual Studio

Tags: c

I am trying to use Safe C library available free at sourceforge website.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/safeclib/

I compiled this library as .a static library using MingW and trying to use it in Visual Studio 2008.

I am facing following issues:

1. Safe C library has same function names as defined in Visual Studio. For example strcpy_s, it is giving me redefinition error.
2. I don't know the consequences using .a library which is not compiled in MS environment but using in Visual Studio. Will there be any issues?
3. Is there any sample or example using this library in Visual Studio environment?

Please answer me as soon as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Why? Considering that it was Microsoft who originally proposed the "safe" interface, why would you want to use an alternate implementation? As you  noticed in 1. the functions are already available with the compiler.

Comment: @BoPersson, Actually there are some functions which are not present in Microsoft version of safe library. For example, Strlen does not have safe version as it has in sourceforge version.

Comment: Ok, so it might be called [`strnlen_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50ty2zh(v=vs.90).aspx), but it is available.

Comment: There are many others. Following is the list.

- Strlen.
- strchr
- strcmp
- strrchr
- memset
- strcasecmp
- strncasecmp
- memcmp

Comment: @BoPersson, Can you help finding secure functions for the list I provided in previous comment?